# Material-ui Official SSR example not working in production servers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I deployed the [official material-ui ssr example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/ssr) to Microsoft Azure, it doesn't work. I also deployed it to Heroku, it still doesn't work. On my local machine and on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/ssr) , everything looks good. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you check browser console or Azure/Heroku logs?

Comment: We can't solve it by code, or change some configurations. So my answer just give you some suggestions.

Comment: @PramodMali It doesn't show any logs on the console. I got some Azure error logs similar to the ones Jason highlited. Thanks for your response

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan for your detailed response. It helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can choose `docker` when you create webapp services. I think it will help you solve the issue.

**PRIVIOUS**

I think this project has some bug in it.

You can [raise a support on azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), or submit a issue on github.

I have try to use many ways to deploy `ssr` project.

1. Continuous deployment to Azure App Service **[Failed]**
2. FTP, then run start command. **[Failed]**
3. Use VSCode to publish. **[Failed]**
4. Paste zip file into kudu. **[Failed]**

After all the attempts, I guess that a certain command of the project may take up a lot of resources, so this project has potential bugs, and the azure team can assist in finding the cause of the deployment failure.

This is my error msg.

[image]